# Сохранение содержимого input после перехода на другую страницу

Tags: php

Есть 2 формы на одной странице и 4 на другой. Человек вводит первые две формы и нажимает на кнопку, после чего его перебрасывает на страницу с 4 формами, причем из этих четырёх - две, которые он ввел ранее. Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы то, что он ввел в те 2 формы сохранились при переходе на страницу с 4 формами и были уже заполнены?

То есть я ввел в 2 формы текст, нажал на кнопку, меня перебросило на страницу с 4 формами, где 2 уже заполнены.

Извиняюсь за сложность пояснения. Прошу  помочь, рассказать что нужно для этого сделать. Я так понимаю, что дело в post запросе, но где задавать переменную и как её нужно вставить - не понимаю!

Comment: Что конкретно вам не понятно? В поисковике можно найти море примеров по вашему запросу

Comment: @ArchDemon Я смотрел, что это делается с помощью JSON, но можно ли попроще, с php, например?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

страница 1

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
    <input name="var1" type="text">
</form>
```

страница 2 (page2.php)

```
<form action="page3.php" method="post">
    <input name="var1" type="text" value="<?= $_POST['var1'] ?? null; ?>">
    <input name="var2" type="text">
</form>
```

Comment: Для понимания вам того, что я написал вот мой код. https://jsfiddle.net/Alexey995/Ly409gkm/1/  Я сделал как у вас, но ругается насчет ?? и = в начале, а без них не работает. У вас точно рабочий код ?

Comment: А все, echo в начале не прописал. спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Делать ajax отправку при потере фокуса - самый правильный вариант.
Так же можно писать в localStorage или sessionStorage браузера, по ситуации